# Plant determination: Lilium monadelphum versus L. szovitsianum

Tags: botany, taxonomy

*Lilium monadelphum*, *L. szovitsianum* and *L. armenicum* belong to group of yellow flowering *Lilium* species and they are both often cultivated.

These species come from Caucasus area, so the first two are both described in the Flora of SSSR (4th volume). However, I find the dichotonic key description incomplete, and, based on the key, I am not able to clearly distinguish these species. *Lilium armenicum* is described by some authors as a variety of *L. szovitsianum* or as a subspecies of *L. monadelphum*.

What are your experiences with determination of these species?